# Display records from SQL Server database into table in ASP Classic

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I am able to display my records from SQL Server db in a table. And now, I am trying to place them in 3 rows & 2 columns table. That's mean if there are two records in total, they should appear side by side instead of one after another.  I can get is repeated records using the following code.

```
<%
Sub B00_DisplayRecords()
Do while not registerRS.eof
counter=counter+1
if counter=41 then
counter=0
counter=counter+1
end if
%>

<tr>    
   <th width="50" font class="tblhdr" style="width:400px;"><%=registerRS.Fields("SchoolId")%> - <%=registerRS.Fields("Organization")%></td>   
   <th width="50" font class="tblhdr" style="width:400px;"><%=registerRS.Fields("SchoolId")%> - <%=registerRS.Fields("Organization")%></td>   
</tr>    
<tr> 
   <td width="50" font class="pgcont" valing=left style="width:400px;" align="left">ProductId: <%=registerRS.Fields("ProductId")%></td>
   <td width="50" font class="pgcont" valing=left style="width:400px;" align="left">ProductId: <%=registerRS.Fields("ProductId")%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td width="50" font class="pgcont" valing=left style="width:400px;" align="left">Qty: <%=registerRS.Fields("Qty")%></td>
   <td width="50" font class="pgcont" valing=left style="width:400px;" align="left">Qty: <%=registerRS.Fields("Qty")%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td width="50" font class="pgcont" valing=left style="width:400px;" align="left">Class: <%=registerRS.Fields("class")%></td>
   <td width="50" font class="pgcont" valing=left style="width:400px;" align="left">Class: <%=registerRS.Fields("class")%></td>
</tr>        

<%
registerRS.movenext
loop
registerRS.close
set registerRS=nothing 
End sub
%>
```

Comment: You could just use line break. Doesn't look like any of the records will wrap. Do as I stated below to make columns but put each record in a single td

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Do until rs.eof

    r = r + 1

    If r = 1 then
        Response.write "<tr>"
    End if

    ' data display

    If r = 3 then
        Response.write "</tr>"
    End if

    If r = 3 then r = 1

Rs.movenext
Loop

If r = 2 ' write extra td and end tr
If r = 1 ' write 2 td and end tr
```